# Why can some Java data types be initialized in the declaration and others cannot?

Tags: java

I am wondering, why some data types can be initialized and declared at the same time in Java, while others cannot?

For example, Strings and int data types can be initialized immediately, outside of any constructor.

```
// This works fine
public class SomeClass {
    String someString = "This variable is initialized";
    int someInt = 5;
}
```

This does not work, the data type here is a vector:

```
public class SomeClass {
    Vector<String> someVector = new Vector<>();
    someVector.add("Test"); // This doesn't work
}
```

Adding values to the vector works inside a constructor or function, but why can't it work outside like the other data types?

Comment: `someVector.add("Test");` is not an initialization; it's a method call statement. The previous line is actually an initialization.

Comment: Yes, why does it have to be inside a function?

Comment: Partially because Java is designed that way. Outside of a function, it's somewhat ambiguous as to when the code should execute; it would be better to put any non-trivial initializations in a constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class SomeClass {
    String someString = "This variable is initialized";
    int someInt = 5;
    someInt++;  // this won't work..why??
}
```

++ for integer variable and add for Vector is analogous.You can only create/declare/initialize objects/primitives.

someVector.add("Test");

Here you are trying to manipulate object using the methods.This is not initialization. This needs to be inside some method.

You have already created the object in

```
`Vector<String> someVector = new Vector<>();`//create an empty vector that will be used to store multiple String objects
```

It has to be inside a method because java is purely an object oriented language. You need classes and methods to work with. You are creating a global variable. Now this manipulation can be done only in methods or inside constructor if you need it to contain some data.

Comment: OP asked *why* it has to be within a method.

Comment: Because instance of  SomeClass  is not created yet, and you trying to perform some manipulations with object that wasn't initialized yet.

Comment: But isn't initializing a string also manipulating the string object as well?

Comment: nope.for ex  `int i = 0` is just plain initialization. When you try to change this variables value, it will be considered as manipulation like `i++, i--` etc. for string when you try to use `replace()` etc that will be considered as manipulation

Comment: Vector is not a datatype. It is an object that can store multiple objects of various types.

Answer (score 2):

You can put variable declarations in a class but not statements. You could use:

```
public class SomeClass {
    Vector<String> someVector = new Vector<>();
    { // this is implicitly part of the constructor function
        someVector.add("Test");
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure this is valid code. `someVector` is not defined with the scope of the brace. I think you were trying to use [double bracket initialization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DoubleBraceInitialization)

Comment: @cricket_007 I'm pretty sure that someVector is in scope because it's a class member variable. The `someVector.add` part is implicitly added to all the constructors right after the `super()` call.

Comment: these blocks are also called `init block`.
@cricket_007 the link you've shared is for `static block initialization`.

Comment: @AnkitDeshpande - I was referring to the fourth code block in that link with `new HashSet() {{ add(); }}`. I think those are different than static blocks.

Comment: @cricket_007 oh yes..indeed.

Answer (score 1):

`class SomeClass` is just declaration of some object, when you calling 
SomeClass var = new SomeClass(), jvm defining memory for this object and all it's properties.

So if you have `private int prop` compiler will define 32 bit in ram.
`private int prop = 10` just mean that you init this memory cell with value of 10.
But, on this step you cant perform any operation on this property.

In same way you can declare Vector with default values:

```
  public String[] a = new String[]{"1"};
  public Vector<String> v = new Vector<>(Arrays.asList(a));
  //equal, but with one variable
  public Vector<String> v = new Vector<>(Arrays.asList(new String[]{"1"}));
```

Comment: This is too low-level for what OP is asking

Comment: It is a good answer but declaring a Vector with default values doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Yes, sorry, it's been a while when i last time worked with java. I updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

This `someVector.add("Test");` is a call statment not an initialization,you can have a declaration of some object or some variable and initialize them, but the call method statement should be inside a method like this:

```
 public class SomeClass {
    Vector<String> someVector = new Vector<>();
    public void someMethod(){
    someVector.add("Test"); // This does work
    }
  }
```